# How to perform a stratified train_test_split without shuffle?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

While exploring different use cases, I got an error while doing the stratified train_test_split without `shuffle`. This was helpful for time series data, but for demonstration purposes, providing a simple dataset.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Sample DataFrame, replace this with your actual DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'feature1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'target': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
})

# Splitting the DataFrame into two equal parts while stratifying on the 'target' column
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, stratify=data['target'], random_state=42)
train_df, test_df
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Stratified train/test split is not implemented for shuffle=False
```

Is there a better way to split the data frame by `test_size` by maintaining the order(ascending or descending)?

Answer (score 1):

you can just add a dummy order column, run the `train_test_split` with `shuffle=True`, and then sort your train/test dataset on the dummy column.

the idea is pretty much like:

```
data['DUMMY_IND'] = range(df.shape[0])
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True, stratify=data['target'], random_state=42)

train_df = train_df.sort_values('DUMMY_IND')
test_df = test_df.sort_values('DUMMY_IND')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation if shuffle=False then stratify must be None.

If you want to split data and have first 80% rows in train and 20% tail in test you have no guarantee that your sampels will be stratified. If you want them stratified you need to accept that some of first/middle columns be in test.

Assume your dataset is sorted by target. Stratification means that train and test must have similar distribution. It will not happen if you put tail of a dataframe in test